# How to access a running programs API

Tags: python, api, subprocess

I have a "process A" that provides an API with python commands such as "importModel" or "openScene", is it possible to call these API commands from a python script for a already open version of "process A".

Using the subprocess and os modules I've been able to launch a new version of process A with command arguments doing what I want but I cant seem to find a way to do it for an already open version.

Unfortunately I'm more stuck with the concepts than the code at the moment.

I want to be able to manipulate "process A"'s API from my python script, is this even possible, is using the subprocess module the right way to go or should I be using another method?

Comment: No, you can't generally get inside an existing process like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Barmer, should help narrow down how i'm going to approach this.